# ASUS X551C notebook not turning on

Tags: asus-laptop

I have an ASUS X551C(A) that is not responding when pressing the power button.

I have the cover off and I can get a reading of 19.8v via a voltmeter set to read to 20 DCV by earthing the black to a motherboard screw and attaching the positive red lead to one of the rear solders behind the back of the power socket on the motherboard.

I am not getting any response from the power button, How do I test if it is the power button or the motherboard is faulty?  Don;t want the expense of a motherboard if we then find its a power switch fault.

Comment: Only real test is to replace the power switch, doubt it costs much if available. I have put quite a few in Dell and HP laptops.

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem with X550CC today.

What I did to fix it was replace the **Power Board 6-pin cable**.

Comment: Hi! Could you by any chance explain a bit more in detail how you replaced it, what was needed, etc?

Comment: Cable itself and a screwdriver. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsQFt9c6E0Q